# only few contents of .ipa file are getting loaded into the device when sinked via itunes

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes

I am developing an application in which I placed a bunch of books in my resources folder of my app. When I load the app into the device from Xcode, all the books are visible in the iPad.

When I load the same app in .ipa format into device using iTunes in the same iPad, only a few books are being loaded (done as ad-hoc).

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem or issue?
Is there anything with provisioning profiles (developer or distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, extract .ipa file by stuffit expander. By that you will get the binary file. Please check those resources are there or not. If yes then might be that older ipa file already installed in your itunes(PC). Delete it and then try to install the ipa file. If no then may be issue while compilation.

Comment: Thank you pragnesh .I ensured that the resources are in the .ipa file.what are the possible issues while compilation.

Comment: If all resources are there in binary file then may be older version of application is getting install from PC as i have already said. If all resource not there then may be, By Mistake, you have remove that file from compilation by selecting and clicking info from xcode.